# How to catch Glide Exceptions Properly?

Tags: android-image, filenotfoundexception, android-glide

Am using Glide 4.x and getting FileNotFoundException as the URL returns 404. I tried to catch the exception using the RequestListener. But it is not Caching this Exception.

```
GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                System.out.println("MainActivity.onLoadFailed"+e.getMessage());
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                System.out.println("MainActivity.onResourceReady");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).transform(new CircleCrop()).into(profileImage);
```

Log as Follows:

> 2019-03-20 17:48:07.134 32233-32233/com.zyta.zflikz W/Glide: Load
>   failed for
>   https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg
>   with size [183x183]
>       class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>       There were 2 causes:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>         Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>           Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg
>         Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>           Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg
>         Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
>   LoadPath{StringUri->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
>           Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
>   DecodePath{StringUri->Drawable->Drawable}
>           Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
>   DecodePath{StringUri->Bitmap->Drawable} 2019-03-20 17:48:07.135
>   32233-32233/com.zyta.zflikz I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 2)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:106)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:59)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
>   2019-03-20 17:48:07.137 32233-32233/com.zyta.zflikz I/Glide: Root
>   cause (2 of 2)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-UxjwFuQRjXA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACLGyWByUX_zz0_9075kpV4xIdPmN_dtNQ/s96-c/photo.jpg
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:106)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:59)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherFailed(DecodeJob.java:397)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onLoadFailed(SourceGenerator.java:119)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:65)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:272)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>           at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
>   2019-03-20 17:48:07.138 32233-32233/com.zyta.zflikz I/System.out:
>   MainActivity.onLoadFailedFailed to load resource

Please let me know if anybody has a Fix or Alternate Solution for this.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @kdblue I have added solution for this. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

This Issue is addressed by Making another call with `Glide` in local Image from `Drawable` in error method.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.YourIconForPlaceholder)
    .error(R.drawable.YourIconWhenfailed)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: thank you for this. An example would have helped even more

                      Glide.with(this)
                        .load(uri.toString())
                        .error(Glide.with(image_view).load(R.drawable.space))
                        .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                        .into(image_view);